# How do I tell if a site is being hosted in the ASP Development Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to do this at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard server variables associated with IIS (`INSTANCE_ID`, `INSTANCE_META_PATH`), and `SERVER_SOFTWARE` all appear to be empty when examined from apps running on the ASP.NET Development Server. I would suggest examining their contents via `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Since I always compile my code for "Release" to normal servers and "Debug" for local code building, I always take advantage of

```
#if DEBUG
  //Some code that only happens in debug mode
#else
  //Production code (frequently connection strings)
#endif
```

Of course, if you forget to switch to "Release" mode when you publish, it's bad news :)

Answer (score 0):

a bit indirect: HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing it from a different machine it can't be the ASP.NET Development Server ("Casini")

Answer (score -2):

You could check and see if it's being hosted not on port 80 (since the dev server will by default give you a rather random port number)

Comment: By default this might work, but you can have IIS run on any port you want in a pinch.